# match function in R for version 4.0.4

Tags: r, match, bioinformatics

I have 2 large datasets. One is **DB** as the database and one is the **raw** for my own data :

*just a sample of the 2 dataframes:*

```
DB:
| rel.genes |        code           | description |
|    fla    | VFG002519(gbYP_109887)| sahashdkjas |
|    un     | YP_105432             | sashjkas    |

raw:
| species |   sacver | qacver |
|   saa   | YP_109887| 122134 |
|   saa   | YP_105432| 42234  |
```

I want to match the sacver data of the **raw** to the code column of the **DB** dataframe. If the sacver is found in one row of the code, it should give the output of the corresponding **"rel.genes"** from the DB dataframe to a new column in the raw dataframe. I used to this easily with this code:

`raw$genes <- DB$rel.genes[match(raw$sacver,DB$code)]`

It should produce this table:

```
| species |  sacver  | qacver | genes |
|    saa  | YP_109887| 123214 |  fla  |
|    saa  | YP_105432| 42234  |   un  |
```

Now that I updated my R to version 4.0.4, this code doesn't work anymore. Instead of having the rel.genes as the output, it just has "NA" for all rows of the new genes column.

What should I change with my code?

Comment: Your code works fine here (version 4.0.4)

Could be something else? Perhaps data now has leading or trailing spaces for some reason that it didnt have before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` is looking for *exact* matches, and `"VFG002519(gbYP_109887)" != "YP_109887"`. If you want partial matching, then I suggest `fuzzyjoin`:

```r
fuzzyjoin::regex_right_join(DB, raw, by = c("code" = "sacver"))
#   rel.genes                   code description species    sacver qacver
# 1       fla VFG002519(gbYP_109887) sahashdkjas     saa YP_109887 122134
# 2        un              YP_105432    sashjkas     saa YP_105432  42234
```

The risk of this is partial matches. For example, if there exists `raw$sacver` with just `YP_10988` (no `7`), then it would match. This would result in either multiple matches for a row or at least a match where none should be. For example,

```r
raw2 <- rbind(raw, data.frame(species = "saa", sacver = "YP_10988", qacver = 122135L))
raw2
#   species    sacver qacver
# 1     saa YP_109887 122134
# 2     saa YP_105432  42234
# 3     saa  YP_10988 122135

fuzzyjoin::regex_right_join(DB, raw2, by = c("code" = "sacver"))
#   rel.genes                   code description species    sacver qacver
# 1       fla VFG002519(gbYP_109887) sahashdkjas     saa YP_109887 122134
# 2        un              YP_105432    sashjkas     saa YP_105432  42234
# 3       fla VFG002519(gbYP_109887) sahashdkjas     saa  YP_10988 122135
```

The third row is a double-match (notice `122135`, the new `qacver` I added).

To mitigate this risk, it will help to refine `raw` (which contains the "pattern" of the regex join) to include regex "word boundaries":

```r
raw2$sacver_ptn <- paste0("\\b", raw2$sacver, "\\b")
raw2
#   species    sacver qacver      sacver_ptn
# 1     saa YP_109887 122134 \\bYP_109887\\b
# 2     saa YP_105432  42234 \\bYP_105432\\b
# 3     saa  YP_10988 122135  \\bYP_10988\\b

fuzzyjoin::regex_right_join(DB, raw2, by = c("code" = "sacver_ptn"))
#   rel.genes      code description species    sacver qacver      sacver_ptn
# 1      <NA>      <NA>        <NA>     saa YP_109887 122134 \\bYP_109887\\b
# 2        un YP_105432    sashjkas     saa YP_105432  42234 \\bYP_105432\\b
# 3      <NA>      <NA>        <NA>     saa  YP_10988 122135  \\bYP_10988\\b
```

Unfortunately, in your example, you have `gbYP_109887`, where the `gb` does not trigger a word-boundary like we would like. For that, I'll relax the boundaries to be on the number side:

```r
raw2$sacver_ptn <- paste0(raw2$sacver, "\\b")
raw2
#   species    sacver qacver   sacver_ptn
# 1     saa YP_109887 122134 YP_109887\\b
# 2     saa YP_105432  42234 YP_105432\\b
# 3     saa  YP_10988 122135  YP_10988\\b

fuzzyjoin::regex_right_join(DB, raw2, by = c("code" = "sacver_ptn"))
#   rel.genes                   code description species    sacver qacver   sacver_ptn
# 1       fla VFG002519(gbYP_109887) sahashdkjas     saa YP_109887 122134 YP_109887\\b
# 2        un              YP_105432    sashjkas     saa YP_105432  42234 YP_105432\\b
# 3      <NA>                   <NA>        <NA>     saa  YP_10988 122135  YP_10988\\b
```

In this case, my new `YP_10988` matched none of the `DB` entries, so it has nothing in `rel.genes`.